# Select count of dates older than x days

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

My example table:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| username |        time         |
+----------+---------------------+
| john     | 2013-02-04 17:39:43 |
| john     | 2013-02-03 00:21:31 |
| peter    | 2013-02-02 15:04:53 |
| grace    | 2013-02-02 03:57:43 |
| peter    | 2013-02-03 15:36:15 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

This table registers activities from users. I need to count the number of users whose last activity date was more than 30 days ago.

I had developed this query:

```
SELECT
  username,
  MAX(time),
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(time)) as diff
FROM tracking
GROUP BY username
HAVING diff > 30
```

Which effectively returns the list of users whose activities are more than 30 days ago, along with the date of that last activity.

But I need the **count** of this list, not the list itself. Is there any way I can count the list?

**NOTES:**

- I can only rely on **SQL** statements, I can't use **PHP** or **ASP** or anything else.
- I can't use **STORED PROCEDURES**.
- I don't need performance, as this statement will only be run once in a while.

Comment: Why not just use that as a subquery and select count(*) FROm it?

Comment: I can't use as subquery a list with more than 1 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple way:

```
SELECT count(distinct username) - 
       count(distinct case when DATEDIFF(NOW(), time) <= 30 then username end) as numusers
FROM tracking
```

This takes the total number of users and subtracts the count of the ones with activity in the last 30 days.

Comment: That returns `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @Veehmot . . . I missed that all important *last* activity date.  I revised the query to take this into account.

Comment: How does this work? Care to elaborate an explanation or link to a resources where this technique is explained/

Comment: @Veehmot . . . Gosh, I thought I did.  The first `count(distinct)` is the number of users.  The second is the number of users who have had activity in the last 30 days.  The difference is users with no activity in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

Just like that?

```
Select count(*) as Num FROM
  (
 SELECT
   username,
    MAX(time),
     DATEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(time)) as diff
     FROM tracking
 GROUP BY username
 HAVING diff > 30
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted the other one because it was better matched with the rest of my queries.